# Taking snapshot from AWS Open Search for backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions

While taking snapshot from the AWS Open Search using S3 and Kibana getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [{
            "type": "security_exception",
            "reason": "no permissions for [cluster:admin/repository/put] and User [name=arn:aws:iam::999988887777:user/username, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]"
    }],
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "no permissions for [cluster:admin/repository/put] and User [name=arn:aws:iam::999988887777:user/username, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]"
    },
    "status": 403
}
```

I tried everything using the AWS documentation but unable to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are encountering indicates that the IAM user associated with the provided ARN does not have the necessary permissions to perform the required action in OpenSearch. To resolve this issue and enable snapshots from OpenSearch to S3 using Kibana, you need to grant the appropriate permissions to the IAM user.

For instructions and troubleshooting steps, refer to the medium article - **https://medium.com/vectoscalar/how-to-trigger-snapshots-of-indices-in-aws-opensearch-and-store-them-in-s3-using-ec2-979f6c8019f0**

Comment: Thanks, the article was helpful and did solve my issue.

Comment: Same here. `Click on “manage mapping” and include the user ARN in the map user field, then click on “Map”.` line is what I was looking for.